# I cannot post html input to php

Tags: php, html

I'm pretty new to using html and php, and its my first time building a website. I'm trying to use php to have users create accounts on my website. Here is my html code.

```
<form action="postinfo.php" method="post">
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
              <td>First Name:</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="firstname" size="20" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Last Name:</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="lastname" size="20" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Email Address:</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="emailaddress" size="20" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Username:</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username" size="20" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="password" name="password" size="20" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Confirm Password:</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="password" name="repassword" size="20" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan ="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Here is my php code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>signupinfo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Account information</p>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
            }

            echo $firstname . ["</br>"];
            echo $firstname . ["</br>"];
            echo $firstname . ["</br>"];
            echo $firstname . ["</br>"];
            echo $firstname . ["</br>"];
        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

when I click the submit button, it says Cannot POST /postinfo.php

is there an issue with formatting the code? I have no idea how to solve it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Likely your action attribute path is wrong

Comment: Is the file indeed called postinfo.php? Case sensitively? Also, `</br>` is an error; where did you get that from? There are no HTML constructs that consist of only an end tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Form Cannot POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450296/html-form-cannot-post) are you running this code on a webserver?

Comment: Both 'accounts.html' and 'postinfo.php' are in the file 'root'. @Picard I'm using Brackets and testing the code on local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php [] is an array. And you tried to echo an array. This is the main reason for not working. Try this code

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];

            echo $firstname . "</br>";
            echo $firstname . "</br>";
            echo $firstname . "</br>";
            echo $firstname . "</br>";
            echo $firstname . "</br>";            

        }
    ?>
```

Before use this code make sure about the correct action url.